# How to parse a csv file with d3 when parser is not the comma

Tags: javascript, parsing, csv, d3.js

I'm working with csv document that I import thanks to d3. Unfortunatelly, the parser is not allways the comma and I didn't find where the parser is recorded in the file architecture... anyway.
Now, I know that my parser is a semicolon, then I've tried to use the dsv function like this

> var csvfile= d3.dsv(";", VariableWithcsvFileInside);

but `console.log(data);`  return this :

> function e(n,e,i){arguments.length<3&&(i=e,e=null);var
>   a=Cn(n,t,null==e?r:u(e),i);return a.row=function(n){return
>   arguments.length?a.response(null==(e=n)?r:u(n)):e},a}

Is there a script that I have to import or something I do wrong?
Thanks for anwering.

PS : `var csvfile = d3.csv.parse(VariableWithcsvFileInside);`works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to tell what's happening, because you didn't include the code that loads and parses the data from a url, but this is how it should work:

```
// ssv is "Semicolon Separated Values" parser
var ssv = d3.dsv(";", "text/plain");

// Load and (later, asynchronously) parse the data
ssv(url, function(data) {
  console.log(data); // should log an array of parsed values
});
```

If the data is already loaded and just needs to be parsed then the 2nd line becomes:

```
var data = ssv.parse(stringOfDataThatWasAlreadyLoaded);
console.log(data); // should log an array of parsed values
```

Comment: I used this code to import my data by drag and drop: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/  (full code at the end of the page)

In your solution, I need to know the URL ("text/plain"), but I don't have this URL. I just have a data which contain all the file...

Comment: @pierreGuillaume, the 2nd code snippet I included is for parsing data that's already loaded.

Comment: "Text/plain" is not a URL, it's a MIME type. Just leave it as it is.

Comment: OK!! I didn't know this concept of MIME type, thanks a lot!