# D3 line chart - Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I got this CSV data (just a sample- it is bigger):

```
value;count
25;1
28;1
29;3
31;2
34;1
36;1
37;2
```

I could not find any example which shows line chart without Date function so I modified the example to make linear scales but it does not work. I am trying to make line chart with this code but I get Error:  attribute d: Expected number

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.value); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.count); });

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("exp2.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.value = +d.value;
      d.count = +d.count;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});
```

Comment: Is that CSV correct? CSV is **comma** separated... anyway, the code has no problem: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/8q3rhn5x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GerardoFurtado pointed out your data is not `csv` (ie **comma** separated) but semi-colon separated.  My initial thought was to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090611/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-with-d3-when-parser-is-not-the-comma) but it looks like the syntax has changed enough in version 4 that I new answer is warranted.

Do this:

```
// set up a parser
var parser = d3.dsvFormat(';').parse;

// get the data as text
d3.text("exp2.csv", function(error, data) {

  if (error) throw error;

  // now parse the data
  data = parser(data);

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.value = +d.value;
    d.count = +d.count;
  });

  ...
```

Here's a full [running example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NryYyS0tgt7XuQNmBb4N?p=preview).

Comment: I tried it with complete dataset but it fails - http://plnkr.co/edit/XQbRDNJzUfMxOh8Y1S7q?p=preview I removed the parser & made the data real csv. Is the dataset too large?

Comment: @darude, well you changed your file to **commas**.  Your question had **semi-colons** and that was the whole reason for my answer.  If you change your file to **commas** your [original code was correct](http://plnkr.co/edit/EFuRGfFftIqlM1dOxFcQ?p=preview).

Comment: Ah I see - d3.csv("exp2.csv", function(error, data) x d3.text("exp2.csv", function(error, data). Thank you a lot!